# How do I get a child's parents in an array.filter() callback function when they were excluded by the filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Today I discovered the `array.filter()` method and its associated callback function.

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var treeAry = [
      {"id" : "200", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "300", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "400", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "500", "parent": "300", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "600", "parent": "300", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "700", "parent": "400", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "800", "parent": "400", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "900", "parent": "200", "type" : "6"},
      {"id" : "1000", "parent": "200", "type" : "9"},
      {"id" : "1100", "parent": "200", "type" : "8"},
];
```

I was successfully able to filter for type 5:

```
  filteredAry = [];

  filteredAry = treeAry.filter(function(val, index, ary){

    /*get all type 5*/
    return val.type === '5';

    /*get all type 5 or type 1*/
    //return val.type === '1' || val.type === '5';

  });

  console.dir(filteredAry)
```

**Here's my question:**

Although I'm able to filter for type 5, I also need Type 5's parents (a child's `parent` references the `id`, and a `parent` can be a #).  Essentially, my results should include anything with type 5, and then also record `id 300` and `400`.  It **should not** include `id 200`.

Should I run some sort of for each loop on `filteredAry[]` to find and push the corresponding item in `treeAry[]`?  Shouldn't I be able to use the `index` and `ary` arguments to get the parents somehow?

Sorry, I don't know how to do this and would love your help.  Just need a push in the right direction, Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to map this into a nested tree something like:  `{id:1, children:[{id:3},{id:4]}`?

Comment: @charlietfl no nested tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be

```js
var treeAry = [
      {"id" : "200", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "300", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "400", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "500", "parent": "300", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "600", "parent": "300", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "700", "parent": "400", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "800", "parent": "400", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "900", "parent": "200", "type" : "6"},
      {"id" : "1000", "parent": "200", "type" : "9"},
      {"id" : "1100", "parent": "200", "type" : "8"},
];

  filteredAry = [];
  filteredAry = treeAry.filter(function(val, index, ary){
    /*get all type 5*/
    return val.type === '5' || 
           ary.some(function(item){ 
                return item.parent === val.id && item.type==='5';
              });


  });

  console.dir(filteredAry)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var treeAry = [
      {"id" : "200", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "300", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "400", "parent": "#", "type" : "1"},
      {"id" : "500", "parent": "300", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "600", "parent": "300", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "700", "parent": "400", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "800", "parent": "400", "type" : "5"},
      {"id" : "900", "parent": "200", "type" : "6"},
      {"id" : "1000", "parent": "200", "type" : "9"},
      {"id" : "1100", "parent": "200", "type" : "8"},
];

var result = treeAry.filter(value => {
 return value.type === '5' || treeAry.filter(val => val.parent === value.id && val.type === '5').length > 0;
});

console.log(result)
```

You can replace lambdas (arrow functions) with ordinary functions if ES6 is an issue.